# How to write csv in python efficiently?

Tags: python, csv

I am working on calculating tf-idf in a large document. The number of words I have is more than 80,000. I am trying to write sparse matrix in a csv file. I am using code similar to answered here [How to add a new column to a CSV file using Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11070638/1496376)

The output file is too big in size, exceeding 700 MB for about 30,000 words only. 
So, my question is how to write it efficiently? 
Thank you.

Comment: If you're writing a sparse matrix to CSV, there's really not much you can do about the file size. Would compression solve your needs? You'd get an amazing compression ratio with a file that's mostly commas.

Comment: Additionally, are you just trying to save the information to disk, or are you set on using the .csv format? If the former is true, you have many more options.

Comment: @David think you've covered all the points I was going to make - This question definitely needs to be more clearly defined

Comment: Have you evaluated existing software that computes and stores tf-idf for large documents? Sphinx for example is open source, written in C++ and very space + memory + speed efficient. There is an API for Python. http://sphinxsearch.com/

Comment: @David I have to use this matrix for further stuff. Any suggestions on how should I proceed? I guess saving it in csv is not the optimum solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[CSV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values) is CSV and there is not much you can do about it. You can simply [gzip](http://docs.python.org/2/library/gzip.html) it, if you *really* want to stick with CSV, or you can use some custom format that better fits your needs.

For example you can use a dictionary and export to [JSON](http://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html) format, or create a dedicated object that handles your data and [pickle](http://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html) it.

When I worked with TF-IDF, I used [sqlite](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html) (via [sqlalchemy](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/)) to store documents information, with TF data as dictionary in JSON format. From that I created IDF stats, and later did rest of TFIDF, using [numpy](http://www.numpy.org/)

Comment: Thanks for letting me know about pickle module. I am not using csv now , and pickle file seems to work great for me!

Answer (score 14):

You can easily write directly a gzip file by using the gzip module :

```
import gzip
import csv

f=gzip.open("myfile.csv.gz", "w")
csv_w=csv.writer(f)
for row in to_write :
    csv_w.writerow(row)
f.close()
```

Don't forget to close the file, otherwise the resulting csv.gz file might be unreadable.

You can also do it in a more pythonic style :

```
with gzip.open("myfile.csv.gz", "w") as f :
    csv_w = csv.writer(f)
    ...
```

which guarantees that the file will be closed.

Hope this helps.