# How to get the time needed for decompressing large bz2 files?

Tags: python, compression, bz2

I need to process large bz2 files (~6G) using Python, by decompressing it line-by-line, using `BZ2File.readline()`. The problem is that I want to know how much time is needed for processing the whole file.

I did a lot searches, tried to get the actual size of decompressed file, so that I can know the percentage processed on-the-fly, and hence the time remaining, while the finding is that it seems impossible to know the decompressed file size without decompressing it first (https://stackoverflow.com/a/12647847/7876675).

Besides that decompressing the file takes loads of memory, decompressing takes a lot of time itself. So, can anybody help me to get the remaining processing time on-the-fly?

Comment: Is there anyway of having the decompressed size available to you? If they are files, then someone must know how big the files were in the first place.You might then be able to guess how long the decompression is going to take by how long its taken so far.

Comment: Using the bz2 module you should be able to open it in python as a stream and read each line. that will save you memory. As far as how long will it take, that depends largely on what "process" means to you

Comment: @quamrana I'm afraid no, as indicated in the link I gave above.

Comment: @owen79 Let's take the easiest case: I can record the time for all the lines already read by `readline()`, but I care more about how long remaining to finish this file.

Comment: You might be able to call `tell()` on the file object passed to `BZ2File ` and compare the current position to size of the whole file which will give you an estimate of how much has been processed. That information plus knowing how much time has elapsed so far would be enough to predict how much longer it will take.

Comment: @martineau `tell()` gives you the position in *decompressed* file, but again, you need to know the original file size to estimate the percentage processed.

Comment: Calling `tell()` on the underlying (compressed) file that `BZ2File` is reading (while it's in the middle of doing so) would give you an idea of how much of it has been processed.

Comment: @martineau Thanks for the explanation. You are right about `tell()`, but without knowing the remaining size of the *uncompressed* file, it's still impossible to estimate time left.

Comment: From your last comment I'm afraid you still don't understand. It's not necessary to know the remaining size, just the total size. Calling `tell()` will tell you how much of that total as been processed by `BZ2File` at any given time. For example, suppose that 25% if the total file size has been read so far and it took 5 seconds. The would allow you to estimate that reading the remaining 75% was going to take 4 times that long: i.e. (4 * 5) = 20 seconds.

Comment: As I mentioned in the question description, it seems to be impossible to know the total size (or percentage processed) of uncompressed file, without decompressing the whole file first. @martineau thanks for trying to help.

Comment: Sigh...to do as I'm suggesting, you only need to know the total size of the **compressed** file.

Comment: OK, there is a lot of misunderstandings here. Two things I can get for sure: *compressed* file size, and the position in *uncompressed* file using `tell()`. If you @martineau are suggesting to use `tell()` to estimate the processed percentage of *compressed* file, I have to respectfully disagree, because the compressed file is usually several times smaller than uncompressed file, which means the percentage will soon go beyond 100%. Thanks for your advices indeed, but they didn't solve my problem.

Comment: Yes, I've been suggesting that you use the percentage of the compressed file that has been processed to estimate how much longer it will take to uncompress the rest of it. This won't be completely accurate of course, which is why it's called an _estimate_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can estimate the time remaining based on the *consumption* of *compressed* data, instead of the *production* of *uncompressed* data. The result will be about the same, if the data is relatively homogenous. (If it isn't, then either using the input or the output won't give an accurate estimate anyway.)

You can easily find the size of the compressed file, and use the time spent on the compressed data so far to estimate the time to process the remaining compressed data.

Here is a simple example of using a `BZ2Decompress` object to operate on the input a chunk at a time, showing the read progress (Python 3, getting the file name from the command line):

```
# Decompress a bzip2 file, showing progress based on consumed input.

import sys
import os
import bz2
import time

def proc(input):
    """Decompress and process a piece of a compressed stream"""
    dat = dec.decompress(input)
    got = len(dat)
    if got != 0:    # 0 is common -- waiting for a bzip2 block
        # process dat here
        pass
    return got

# Get the size of the compressed bzip2 file.
path = sys.argv[1]
size = os.path.getsize(path)

# Decompress CHUNK bytes at a time.
CHUNK = 16384
totin = 0
totout = 0
prev = -1
dec = bz2.BZ2Decompressor()
start = time.time()
with open(path, 'rb') as f:
    for chunk in iter(lambda: f.read(CHUNK), b''):
        # feed chunk to decompressor
        got = proc(chunk)

        # handle case of concatenated bz2 streams
        if dec.eof:
            rem = dec.unused_data
            dec = bz2.BZ2Decompressor()
            got += proc(rem)

        # show progress
        totin += len(chunk)
        totout += got
        if got != 0:    # only if a bzip2 block emitted
            frac = round(1000 * totin / size)
            if frac != prev:
                left = (size / totin - 1) * (time.time() - start)
                print(f'\r{frac / 10:.1f}% (~{left:.1f}s left) ', end='')
                prev = frac

# Show the resulting size.
print(end='\r')
print(totout, 'uncompressed bytes')
```

Comment: Yeah, I can get the size of the whole compressed file, but any ideas of getting the consumed size?

Comment: Use `BZ2Decompressor` and only feed it a chunk at a time. Then the consumed size is what you have fed it so far.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to use directly existing high-level APIs provided by the `bz2` Python module and at the same time obtain information from the underlying file handler on how much compressed data has been processed.

```
import bz2
import datetime
import time

with bz2.open(input_filename, 'rt', encoding='utf8') as input_file:
    underlying_file = input_file.buffer._buffer.raw._fp
    underlying_file.seek(0, io.SEEK_END)
    underlying_file_size = underlying_file.tell()
    underlying_file.seek(0, io.SEEK_SET)
    lines_count = 0
    start_time = time.perf_counter()
    progress = f'{0:.2f}%'

    while True:
        line = input_file.readline().strip()
        if not line:
            break

        process_line(line)

        lines_count += 1
        current_position = underlying_file.tell()
        new_progress = f'{current_position / underlying_file_size * 100:.2f}%'
        if progress != new_progress:
            progress = new_progress
            current_time = time.perf_counter()
            elapsed_time = current_time - start_time
            elapsed = datetime.timedelta(seconds=elapsed_time)
            remaining = datetime.timedelta(seconds=(underlying_file_size / current_position - 1) * elapsed_time)
            print(f"{lines_count} lines processed, {progress}, {elapsed} elapsed, {remaining} remaining")
```

If you are not reading text files, but binary files, then you have to use:

```
with bz2.open(input_filename, 'rb') as input_file:
    underlying_file = input_file._buffer.raw._fp
    ...
```

Answer (score -1):

With the help of another answer, finally I found a solution. The idea is to use the size of compressed file processed, total size of compressed file, and the time used to estimate the remaining time. To achieve this,

1. read the compressed file as a byte object into memory: `byte_data`, which is quite fast
2. calculate the size of `byte_data` using `total_size = len(byte_data)`
3. wrap `byte_data` as `byte_f = io.BytesIO(byte_data)`
4. wrap `byte_f` as `bz2f = bz2.BZ2File(byte_f)`
5. during processing, use `pos = byte_f.tell()` get current position in *compressed* file
6. calculate the exact percentage processed `percent = pos/total_size`
7. record time used, and calculate time remaining

After a few seconds, the estimation can become pretty accurate:

```
0.01% processed, 2.00s elapsed, 17514.27s remaining...
0.02% processed, 4.00s elapsed, 20167.48s remaining...
0.03% processed, 6.00s elapsed, 21239.60s remaining...
0.04% processed, 8.00s elapsed, 21818.91s remaining...
0.05% processed, 10.00s elapsed, 22180.76s remaining...
0.05% processed, 12.00s elapsed, 22427.78s remaining...
0.06% processed, 14.00s elapsed, 22661.80s remaining...
0.07% processed, 16.00s elapsed, 22840.45s remaining...
0.08% processed, 18.00s elapsed, 22937.07s remaining...
....
99.97% processed, 22704.28s elapsed, 6.27s remaining...
99.98% processed, 22706.28s elapsed, 4.40s remaining...
99.99% processed, 22708.28s elapsed, 2.45s remaining...
100.00% processed, 22710.28s elapsed, 0.54s remaining...
```

Comment: You do not need to load the whole thing into memory. That will take up unnecessary resources for large files. Use the `BZ2Decompressor` object instead of `BZ2File`, and read chunks at a time, producing output chunks at a time, processing your output at you go.

Comment: @MarkAdler I guess you're right. But in my situation, reading the whole file in memory will make the program faster, and using `BZ2File.readline()` can make the processing a lot easier.