# Add a column from a csv to another csv

Tags: python

I have 2 files named input.csv (composed of one column *count* ) and output.csv (composed of one column *id*).
I want to paste my *count* column in output.csv, just after the *id* column.

Here is my snippet :

```
with open ("/home/julien/input.csv", "r") as csvinput:
    with open ("/home/julien/excel/output.csv", "a") as csvoutput:
        writer = csv.writer(csvoutput, delimiter = ";")

        for row in csv.reader(csvinput, delimiter = ";"):
            if row[0] != "":
                result = row[0]
            else:
                result = ""  

             row.append(result)
         writer.writerow(row)
```

But it doesn't work.

I've been searching the problem for many hours but I'v got no solution. Would you have any tricks to solve my problem ?
Thanks! Julien

Comment: Did you try this answer? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11070527/how-to-add-a-new-column-to-a-csv-file-using-python

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes, I looked at this answer but I guess it's not the same problem I have.

Comment: I'm not real clear on what you mean. Does `paste -d';' /path/to/input.csv /path/to/output.csv` give you what you want? (on the terminal, not python code) If not, please give a few lines of inputs and expected output.

Comment: You need to be more clear on what "doesn't work." In what way is it not working? What is your input? What is your output? What were you expecting? How is the output not matching what you were expecting? etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to work with three files, two for reading and one for writing.
This should work.

```
import csv

in_1_name = "/home/julien/input.csv"
in_2_name = "/home/julien/excel/output.csv"
out_name = "/home/julien/excel/merged.csv"

with open(in_1_name) as in_1, open(in_2_name) as in_2, open(out_name, 'w') as out:
    reader1 = csv.reader(in_1, delimiter=";")
    reader2 = csv.reader(in_2, delimiter=";")
    writer = csv.writer(out, delimiter=";")
    for row1, row2 in zip(reader1, reader2):
        if row1[0] and row2[0]:
            writer.writerow([row1[0], row2[0]])
```

You write the row for each column:

```
            row.append(result)
            writer.writerow(row)
```

Dedent the last line to write only once:

```
            row.append(result)
        writer.writerow(row)
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried your idea but I had the following error message : Traceback (most recent call last):
`File "test.py", line 165, in <module>`
`writer.writerow(row)`
`ValueError: I/O operation on closed file`

Comment: Dedent only one level to the level of `for row in csv.reader(csvinput, delimiter = ";"):`.

Comment: Ok, That's what I just tried (made the edit in my first message). But my output.csv file is only composed of my _id_ column. The _count_  column of input.csv is not present.

Comment: I added a solution that works for me with sample data. Try it out.

Answer (score 1):

1. Open both files for input.
2. Open a new file for output.
3. In a loop, read a line from each, formatting an output line, which is then written to the output file
4. close all the files
5. Programmatically copy your output file on top of the input file
   "output.csv".

Done

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Indeed, it's the workflow I'd like to apply. But I don't exactly find the code to make it work. If it doesn't bother you, could you show it to me please ?

Answer (score 0):

If anyone was given two tables, merging them by using first column of each is very easy. With my library `pyexcel`, you do the merge just like merging tables:

```
>>> from pyexcel import Reader,Writer
>>> f1=Reader("input.csv", delimiter=';')
>>> f2=Reader("output.csv", delimiter=';')
>>> columns = [f1.column_at(0), f2.column_at(0)]
>>> f3=Writer("merged.csv", delimiter=';')
>>> f3.write_columns(columns)
>>> f3.close()
```