# CSV Syntax Error?

Tags: python

Just wondering what's triggering this syntax error:

```
  File "/Users/samuelfinegold/Documents/noodle/add_col.py", line 16

                                                 ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
logout

[Process completed]
```

Script:

```
import csv

# fieldnames = ['name','degrees','area','phone','email','website']

with open('ieca_first_col_fake_text.txt', 'r') as input:
    with open('new_col.txt', 'w') as output:
        writer = csv.writer(output)
        for row in csv.reader(input):
            writer.writerow(row+['Berry'])
            writer.writerow(row.append('new_col')

# with open('ieca_first_col_fake_text.txt','r') as input:
#     with open('new_col_dict.txt','w') as output:
#         dict_writer = csv.DictWriter(output, fieldnames, delimiter = '\t')
#         dict_reader = csv.DictReader(input)
```

Thanks!

Comment: And, what is line 16?

Comment: That is a good question...guessing they think it's the next row that the comp thinks I've enter by not closing the parenthesis

Comment: oic.  Syntax errors at end of file are usually caused by missing close brace or close parenthesis.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You missed a closing `)` on this line:

```
writer.writerow(row.append('new_col')
                                     ^         
                                     |
```

Comment: Any chance you know how to add a column that's tab separated? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17528274/add-column-to-a-tab-delimited-text-file