# Adding python lists as new columns to a csv file

Tags: python, csv

I have a csv file that contains five columns:

```
a1 b1 c1 d1 e1
a2 b2 c2 d2 e2
a3 b3 c3 d3 e3
```

And I have some lists that I want to add to this csv (each list as a new column), so the end result would look something like this:

```
a1 b1 c1 d1 e1 f1 g1 h1
a2 b2 c2 d2 e2 f2 g2 h2
a3 b3 c3 d3 e3 f3 g3 h3
```

I can save these lists as a new csv

```
outputdata=zip(list1,list2,list3,list4)
writer=CsvUnicodeWriter(open("myoutput.csv","wb"))
writer.writerows(output data)
```

But this is not exactly what I need. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11070527/how-to-add-a-new-column-to-a-csv-file-using-python.

Comment: might help to actually show your lists

Comment: @ Padraic My lists are simply numbers i.e., List1 = ['14', '34', '13', '64'...]; List2 = ['34', '65', '12', '90'...], etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The index of the source csv and the zipped lists should match so you can use `enumerate` to track it.

```
zipped = zip(list1, list2, list3, list4)

with open('in.csv', 'rb') as infile, open('out.csv' 'wb') as outfile:
    reader = csv.reader(infile)
    writer = csv.writer(outfile)
    for i, row in enumerate(reader):
        row.extend(zipped[i])
        writer.writerow(row)
```

If you are doing a lot of data wrangling like this however check out the [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org) library.
The pandas code is a bit simpler, although you have to get used to the pandas api, which is based on index labels and vectorised operations.

```
indata = pd.read_csv('in.csv')
zipped = pd.DataFrame(zip(List1, List2, List3, List4)
#axis=1 indicates to concat the frames column wise
outdata = pd.concat([indata, zipped], axis=1)
#we dont want headers and dont want the row labels
outdata.to_csv('out.csv', header=False, index=False)
```

Comment: Thank you! That does indeed look like a solution. However, I get a "sequences expected" error, and I'm not quite sure what to do about it.

Comment: here it is:
   `108     for i, row in enumerate(reader):
    109         outrow = row.extend(zipped[i])
--> 110         writer.writerow(outrow)

Error: sequence expected`

Comment: Oops! Extend returns none as it modifies the object in place. I have updated my answer. Sorry about that, should have tested first.