# Existing Csv - Add Column at last after reading the CSV file - PHP

Tags: php, csv

As after doing the searching the net I was unable to find out the exact solution that I wanted.

> ***NOTE: The CSV is stored at some URL like www.xyz.com/fkLmopfnahe***

After getting data from this URL I have to make a new CSV.

I have a CSV file which have 11 columns and wanted to add the 12th column at last after doing some manipulation with the current data from different columns on the same row.

I want to read the file and then write it to the file,But the file that is coming to me is dynamic with some fixed columns that I have to use for manipulation.

So I want to make sure that the CSV should contain all the data along with the new manipulated data at last column.

Similarly like this but in php : [How to add a new column to a CSV file using Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11070527/how-to-add-a-new-column-to-a-csv-file-using-python?rq=1)

Comment: fgetcvs > manipulate > fputcsv

Comment: @steve Thanks for quick reply, **fgetcvs** didn't find that. Is it **fgetcsv** ?

Comment: Oops, yes, sorry typo.

Comment: Its not going through Oops