# Appending a Column with sum of rows and sorting in python

Tags: python, sorting, csv, count, append

This is a pretty basic question. I want to organize a csv a certain way. So far I have it almost as I want it, and it is pretty fast as well.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import pandas.util.testing as tm; tm.N = 3


data = pd.DataFrame.from_csv('MYDATA.csv')
byqualityissue = data.groupby(["Name","Type"]).size()
df = pd.DataFrame(bytype)

formatted = df.unstack(level=-1)
formatted[np.isnan(formatted)] = 0
formatted.to_csv('bytype.csv', header=True)
```

bytype looks like this:

```
Type          Type1        Type2       Type3
Name  
Company 1      10            0           3
Company 2      4             23          3 
Company 3      3             2           0
```

However, I want it sorted so that the company with the largest total (sum of the row) will be at the top. In this case it should be Company 2 at the top, followed by Company 1, then Company 3. It should select only the top twenty customers to be read in by the rest of my python code.

```
Name,         Type1,    Type2,   Type3
Company 2,     4,        23,       3
Company 1,     10,       0,        3
Company 3,     3,        2,        0
```

I think the best way would be to add up the totals in another column and then sort by descending order. In order to do that I wrote this line:

```
sorted = np.sum(formatted, axis=1)
```

which successfully outputs a total. I looked at [How to add a new column to a CSV file using Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11070527/how-to-add-a-new-column-to-a-csv-file-using-python)

And so wrote:

```
with open('bytype.csv') as csvinput:
    with open('bytype2.csv','w') as csvoutput:
        writer = csv.writer(csvoutput, lineterminator='\n')
        reader = csv.reader(csvinput)

        all = []
        row = next(reader)
        row.append('Total')
        all.append(row)

        for row in reader:
            row.append(np.sum(formatted, axis=1))
            all.append(row)

        writer.writerows(all)
```

But not only am I not getting an output bytype2, but that method seemed to mean re-reading the csv and then appending the column, and THEN I'd still have to sort them. There must be an easier way to do this that I'm missing.

Comment: Just add the column to your dataframe, df[key] = whatever

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I know it's probably as simple as that, but how exactly do you add it? df[newkeytitle] = sorted? How does it know where in the dataframe to put it? I've been teaching myself python for the last week but I'm still very new.

Comment: yes, just use the new col name as the key and whatever you want to add as the value, can you share a little bit if your file?

Comment: The column will be added to the end of the dataframe, the last column.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I can't share my actual data, but I could muster up an example file if you want one. I tried writing df[Total]=sorted but Total as a key is not defined since it's a new column I'm trying to add. So I'm getting (predictably) this error: NameError: name 'Total' is not defined

Comment: it needs to be a string `df["Total"]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answered my own question after tinkering for another day. Here's how I added a column of totals, and then sorted by that column.

```
includingtotals = pd.concat([formatted,pd.DataFrame(formatted.sum(axis=1),columns=['Total'])],axis=1)
sorted = includingtotals.sort_index(by=['Total'], ascending=[False])
sorted.to_csv('byqualityissue.csv', header=True)
```