# Append a new Column with Pandas Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I currently have a python script which pulls in Analytics data and churns out a CSV. I want to be able to add in a column in after the CSV has been created. I know which column number it has to go in and I would also like to populate each cell in that column as far down as the CSV goes.

Is there any simple script, from Pandas, that would allow me to add on a column and populate the cells based on a loop I create?

If any further information is needed please let me know, i'm still very new to python :)

Cheers

Comment: Possible duplicate of [python pandas insert column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33139513/python-pandas-insert-column)

Comment: What is the CSV doing with your question? It seems to me your question is rather: how to insert a column in a dataframe :-) .

Comment: @Lorenzo my suggested dupe covers the csv aspect too :)

Comment: @roganjosh Thanks for the link to the potential dupe, I will go and check it out now :D

Comment: Give us an example of your data, code, etc...