# Add a column to a csv file at specified index with different values

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I would like to add a column to a given index with a different value at each time (that value is computed depending on the values of the row).
This is a sample of my csv:

```
org,repo_name,stars_count,fork_count,commit_count
freeCodeCamp,freeCodeCamp,303178,22005,23183,1703
vuejs,vue,140222,20150,3016,82
twbs,bootstrap,133730,65555,18714,46
...
```

So far I tried the answer provided here: [python pandas insert column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33139513/python-pandas-insert-column)

```py
def func(f):
    files = f
    df = pd.read_csv(files)
    df = df.convert_objects(convert_numeric=True)
    df.insert(2, 'new', 1000)
    df.to_csv(files)
```

I get the result of an added row to index 2 with values 1000.

```
,org,repo_name,new,stars_count,fork_count,commit_count
freeCodeCamp,freeCodeCamp,303178,1000,22005,23183,1703
vuejs,vue,140222,1000,20150,3016,82
twbs,bootstrap,133730,1000,65555,18714,46
...
```

How to modify this to be able to add a specific value to each row instead of adding 1000 everywhere? And how to add a header so I get the following output? Please note that score1... scoreN are int variables, not string and that you can assume that they already been computed.

```
org,repo_name,score,new,stars_count,fork_count,commit_count
freeCodeCamp,freeCodeCamp,303178,score1,22005,23183,1703
vuejs,vue,140222,score2,20150,3016,82
twbs,bootstrap,133730,score3,65555,18714,46
...
```

Thanks.

Comment: How you want your csv to look like? Let us know more about it.

Comment: @AmazingThingsAroundYou Hi, I gave the output that i want at the end (my last code snippet). Is that what you are referring to?

Comment: `df.insert(2,'new',['score{}'.format(i+1) for i in range(len(df))])` ?

Comment: @anky_91, hi, I've edited my post since it seems like it wasn't clear enough. score is not a string, it's a int that is different for each rows.

Comment: @SoyänChardon how are you getting score?

Comment: @anky_91I plan on computing it in another method using the values in my rows and some mathematical function. You can assume for this question that the score is already available.

Comment: @SoyänChardon if it is available you should look if it is available as a list? if yes, just assign the list `df.insert(2,'new',values_score_as_list) `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pandas is close to overkill to only insert a new column into a csv:

```
with open('input.csv') as fdin, open('output.csv', 'w', newline='') as fdout:
    rd = csv.DictReader(fdin)
    fields = list(rd.fieldnames)
    fields.insert(2, 'new')
    wr = csv.DictWriter(fdout, fieldnames=fields)
    wr.writeheader()
    for row in rd:
        row['new'] = compute_val(row)    # or compute_val(*row)
        wr.writerow(row)
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. Unfortunately it doesn't work as instead of inserting a column at index 2 and therefore shifting to the right the others columns, it overwrite the content of the column at index 2. The output is ```freeCodeCamp,freeCodeCamp,0.0628325397113628,22015,23213,1670,``` 

instead of ```freeCodeCamp,freeCodeCamp,0.0628325397113628,303198,22015,23213,1670```

Comment: @SoyänChardon: It worked in my tests. Maybe you should use `fields = list(rd.fieldnames)` to ensure to get a true list. I have edited my post.

Comment: @SergeBellesta Thanks you very much, it now works perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:

```
len_df = len(df.index)+1
df["new"] = ["score"+str(i) for i in range(1,len_df)]
```

I hope this will help you.
ok so this might will be helpful:

```
df["new"].values[2] = score_value
```

Note that score_value is `int`

Comment: Hi, it maybe wasn't clear but score is not a string, it's a int variable that is different for each row, so unfortunately your answer doesn't help. i've edited my post to avoid misunderstandings.

Comment: @SoyänChardon I hope now my edited answer will help you.