# Add a new row to a csv file?

Tags: python, csv

I wanted to know how you can add a new row in python to a csv file. I tried `mydata.to_csv()` and read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11070527/how-to-add-a-new-column-to-a-csv-file-using-python), but I couldn't find out how to do rows. Can anyone help?

Comment: This is an old question. Do a better search. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10715965/add-one-row-in-a-pandas-dataframe

Comment: Oh, sorry! Thanks for the answer!