# How to add list into a new column in csv - python

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv

I have a csv file like this:

```
A,Film, Yes 
B,Grass,No
C,Bottle,No  
D,Love,Yes
E,Red,No
```

And I have a list from the system is like this:

```
['No','No','Yes','Yes','No']
```

How can i add the list to the new column and my expectation is like this:

```
    A,Film, Yes,No
    B,Grass,No,No
    C,Bottle,No,Yes
    D,Love,Yes,Yes
    E,Red,No,No
```

How can i do that?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11070527/how-to-add-a-new-column-to-a-csv-file

Answer (score 0):

Using the CSV module.

**Demo:**

```
import csv
toAdd = ['No','No','Yes','Yes','No']
with open(filename, "r") as infile:
    data = [i.strip().split(",") for i in infile.readlines()]

with open(filename, "w") as outfile:
    writer = csv.writer(outfile, delimiter=",")
    for i, value in enumerate(toAdd, 0):
        v = data[i]
        v.extend([toAdd[i]])
        writer.writerow(v)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `zip`:

```
import csv
with open('filename.csv') as f:
  with open('filename.csv', 'w') as f1:
    headers = ['No','No','Yes','Yes','No'] 
    data = list(csv.reader(f))   
    write = csv.writer(f1)
    write.writerows([a+[b] for a, b in zip(data, headers)])
```

Answer (score 0):

For more complex operations, the csv module should be considered. But to only add the content of a simple list as the last column of a file, simple string processing should be enough:

```
lastcol = ['No','No','Yes','Yes','No']
with open(infile) as fdin, open(outfile, "w") as fdout:
    for i, line in enumerate(fdin):
        print(line.rstrip(), lastcol[i], sep=",", file=fdout)
```

Above just assumes that list is at least as long as the file...

Answer (score -1):

If you want to use the `pandas` library, you can do:

```
import pandas as pd

list = ['No','No','Yes','Yes','No'] 
df = pd.read_csv('data.csv')
df['new_column'] = list
df.to_csv('modified_data.csv')
```

Comment: i don't think author needs to install `pandas` because he simply wants to add a new column