# Including filename when reading a file in Python

Tags: python, filenames

I am trying to read a file in Python using the below code:

```
with open(file) as fp:
    data = fp.read()
```

The above script works well. I however am trying to have the filename included in the output of `data`

How could I have that included.

Edit:

Adding a sample output with the expected result

Current Output:

```
col1,col2,col3
1,Prod_A,10
2,Prod_B,5
```

Expected output:

```
col1,col2,col3,filename
1,Prod_A,10,sales.csv
2,Prod_B,5,sales.csv
```

Comment: `fp.name` contains the name of the file.  is that what you need?

Comment: Well that's awfully unclear. Assuming the file name is `"foo.txt"` and the file content is `"bar"`, you would want `data` to be... what?

Comment: How do you want it "included in the output"?

Comment: Help us to help you. Please add sample input and output.

Comment: `file.split('/')[-1]` (or with'\') gives you the name before you even open it

Comment: How is defined your variable file?

Comment: @hiroprotagonist, I have edited my post with some sample output. hope this helps.

Comment: @Camile, its a list

Comment: @Aran-Fey, trying to include foo as one of the columns in the output. Added a sample output for reference in my initial post.

Comment: Suspected dup: [How to add a new column to a CSV file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11070527/how-to-add-a-new-column-to-a-csv-file)

Answer (score 0):

It might be something as simple as

```
data = {}

with open("test.txt") as fp:
   data['name'] = fp.name
   data['content'] = fp.read()
```

the output would look something like

```
{'name': 'test.txt',
 'content': '124512451245124512451245124512451245124512451245\n'}
```

But it really depends on what you want the structure of `data` to be.

**Edit:** based on the feedback, the example above can be rewritten with a list as

```
data = []

with open("test.txt") as fp:
   data.append(fp.name)
   data.append(fp.read())
```

the output would look like:

```
['test.txt', '124512451245124512451245124512451245124512451245\n']
```

Comment: trying to achieve this using a list

Comment: @scottmartin does the updated answer address your question? If so, please don't forget to close the question :)

Answer (score 0):

Read your csv file and add new column:

```
import csv
import os

m, n = 'sales.csv', 'sales_temp.csv'

with open(m, newline='') as f:
    with open(n, 'w', newline='') as f_temp:
        w = csv.writer(f_temp)

        for r in csv.reader(f):
            w.writerow(r + ['filename']) if r[0] == 'col1' else w.writerow(r + [f.name])

os.remove(m)
os.rename(n, m)
```