# Writing in columns of an excel file from a list of texts

Tags: excel, python-3.x

I have a list of texts (reviews_train) which I gathered from a text file (train.txt).

```
reviews_train = []
for line in open('C:\\Users\\Dell\\Desktop\\New Beginnings\\movie_data\\train.txt', 'r', encoding="utf8"):
    reviews_train.append(line.strip())
```

Suppose `reviews_train = ["Nice movie","Bad film",....]`

I have another result.csv file which looks like

```
company     year
 a          2000
 b          2001
 .
 .
 .
```

What I want to do is add another column text to the existing file to look something like this.

```
company     year     text
 a          2000     Nice movie
 b          2001     Bad film
 .
 .
 .
```

The items of the list should get appended in the new column one after the other.

I am really new to python. Can some one please tell me how to do it? Any help is really aprreciated.

EDIT: My question is not just about adding another column in the .csv file. The column should have the texts in the ***list*** appended row wise.

EDIT: I used the solution given by @J_H but I get this error
[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add a new column to a CSV file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11070527/how-to-add-a-new-column-to-a-csv-file)

Comment: @Ruturaj I edited my question for better understanding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [zip()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip):

```
def get_rows(infile='result.csv'):
    with open(infile) as fin:
        sheet = csv.reader(fin)
        for row in sheet:
            yield list(row)


def get_lines(infile=r'C:\Users\Dell\Desktop\New Beginnings\movie_data\train.txt'):
    return open(infile).readlines()


for row, line in zip(get_rows(), get_lines()):
    row.append(line)
    print(row)
```

With those 3-element rows in hand,
you could e.g. [writerow()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.csvwriter.writerow).

EDIT

The `open()` in your question mentions `'r'` and `encoding='utf8'`,
which I suppressed since `open()` should default to using those.

Apparently you're not using the python3 mentioned in your tag,
or perhaps an ancient version.
PEPs 529 & 540 suggest that since 3.6 windows will default to UTF-8,
just like most platforms.
If your host manages to default to something crazy like CP1252,
then you will certainly want to override that:

```
    return open(infile, encoding='utf8').readlines()
```

Comment: I edited the question and added the error screenshot.