# How to add a add a value to a pre-existing row in a csv file using python

Tags: python, csv

So I am trying to add a value to a pre-existing row in a csv file using python. I have literally scoured the web for any websites, previous StackOverflow Questions which have the answer I am looking for. But I can't find any. So basically, I want to change a csv file from

```
example,example,example
example2,example2,example2
```

to

```
example,example,example,example
example2,example2,example2,example2
```

I don't have any code because I have no idea how I could possibly do it.

Comment: You need to read the CSV from the file, add the column, add the row with the new column, and write the CSV back to a file. I suggest using `csv.DictReader` and `csv.DictWriter` from the standard library.

Comment: instead of `example,example,example,example` add some meaningful data

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add a new column to a CSV file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11070527/how-to-add-a-new-column-to-a-csv-file)

Comment: It almost does, but I am trying to write to the same file

Comment: @deadshot there is this error

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/myname/Desktop/folder123/testing.py", line 9, in <module>
    row = next(reader)
StopIteration

Comment: "I am trying to write to the same file" why same file?

Answer (score 0):

if you want to add column to the last row only you can just append it like this

```
with open("file.csv","a") as csv_file:
    csv_file.write(",example2")
```